# Oracle Forms 6i EXEC_SQL Package

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am using the EXEC_SQL package i have executed a sql string using something like this

```
Count := EXEC_SQL.EXECUTE(cursor_number);
```

I would like to know how can i get the a count of the total number of records returned by the query SQL%ROWCOUNT isn't working for me.

Comment: read this - you have to set a trigger http://flylib.com/books/en/1.587.1.23/1/

Comment: i am not working with database blocks thou any other advice here